# Delaunay Triangulation - Forcing convex hull

Tags: computational-geometry, convex-hulls, triangulation

I was implementing Delaunay Triangulation based on (http://paulbourke.net/papers/triangulate/) under the impression that this triangulation always results convex hull [which is not :( ]. Is there anyway to force Delaunay Triangulation to produce convex hull always?

[image: Concave DA sample image]

Here is an example of when the triangulation does not produce the convex hull.

Comment: First, calculate the convex hull. Second, construct additional points over the hull segments with a distance between them within a global media.

Comment: Your example should contain one more Delaunay edge, then you'll see that the outer loop is actually a convex hull.